# Deploying .Net application from IIS using IP and port without SSL and Domain in a VPS server

Tags: .net, networking, deployment, ip-address, vps

I have purchased a VPS server. The provider gave me two private IP and One Public dedicated IP. When trying to publish website binding with public IP, it asks first for server sign in credentials and then says website not found while the website is ok when binding from private IP and checking from only server browser.

Normally I used to publish my project using server ip and port from IIS. But in VPS that's not happening.

[image: IP list in IIS]

All the IP's in the IIS list is private. As usual when using the project in private IP its ok in the server browser but not from other PC. When using dedicated server ip which is public, then getting this error.

[image: public ip]

even if I give the server username and pass then it says website cannot be found in the address. My firewall is open for the ports.

**I think I may have done some mistake in configuration. Please help me to solve this issue. How to overcome this issue and publish my website using IP and port.**